# I have a class in one file but it calls a function in my main file, in which I call the referred class. How can I make this work?

Tags: python

In my main file `game.py` I define the `foo` function and create a instance of my `Hero` class, defined in the `module.py` file.

```
# module.py
class Hero():
  def __init__(self):
    self.attributes = foo()

# game.py
from module import Hero

def foo():
  ...
  return something

x = Hero()
```

But my `Hero` class needs to use my `foo` function, so it's returning `NameError: name 'foo' is not defined`. That wouldn't happen if I were using a single file:

```
# fullgame.py
def foo():
  ...
  return something

class Hero():
  def __init__(self):
    self.attributes = foo()

x = Hero()
```

How can I make this work? Mostly because I need other classes in other files also use `foo` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If something from module A absolutely needs something from module B and module B absolutely needs something from module A, they are functionally so tightly coupled, you have to wonder if they should perhaps be in the same module.

However, the example you're giving is about some 'main' module `game.py` and a module `module.py` containing some `Hero` class, and you have some function you'd like to be able to use in both.

Either move the `foo()` function to the `module.py` module, and import it from `game.py` to have access to it there as well. Or move the `foo()` function to some other module `utility.py` and import `foo` in both `module.py` and `game.py`.

`utility.py`

```
def foo():
   ...
```

`module.py`

```
from utility import foo

class Hero:
   def __init__():
      foo()
```

`game.py`

```
from module import Hero
from utility import foo

foo()  # calling foo()
h = Hero()  # Hero will call foo()
```

The problem you were having is called a circular reference, and it can't work because Python cannot figure out in what order to compile your code, if it can even be compiled.

In your case, it could in theory be compiled, as long as `foo()` doesn't use the `Hero` class, but it would be a lot of work for the analyser to figure that out, and it would be hard to read and maintain code as well. Most languages disallow circular references, for good reason.

If, for whatever obscure reason (and you have to wonder if that's really a good one), you must have the `foo()` function in `game.py` and still solve this problem, you can pass the function to the part of `Hero` that needs it.

For example:
`game.py`

```
from module.py import Hero

def foo():
   print('This must happen here for mysterious and possibly bad reasons.')

h = Hero()
h.do_something_with_a_function(foo)
```

`module.py`

```
class Hero:
   def do_something_with_a_function(f):
      f()  # when called with foo, f will be foo, so foo() is called
```

Not recommended, but you get the idea, and in some cases, callback functions like these are the right solution.

In my experience, beginning programmers get into these types of shenanigans "because I don't want so many files", with is a *bad* reason.